# What does assigning -1 to $#array do?

Tags: perl

Take this code:

```
$#mdCntrs = -1;
```

`$#array` returns the index of last element of array and returns `-1` when array is empty.

But this assigning `-1`, what does that mean?

Comment: It's better to post the function / part of your program which has this line you mentioned. Then it's easy to understand and we can provide more information (easily)

Answer (score 8):

It changes the length of the array, in this case it will clear the entire array.

From [perldoc perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html):

> Assigning to `$#days` actually changes the length of the array.
>   Shortening an array this way destroys intervening values.

It goes on to say:

> The following are equivalent:
>
> ```
>     @whatever = ();
>     $#whatever = -1;
> ```

Comment: In practice I prefer using `@foo = ()` because it's so much clearer.